# Android OOM Exception in Moto Z play

Tags: android

Today I faced a weird issue, when i tried to run an app in Moto Z play (which is an XXHDPI device) which inflates a custom view with few image then the app throw OOM exception for bitmap. But the same app runs fine in other XXHDPI deices.

I am not able to understand why this issue occurs if there is a problem with the image then it should be appearing in every XXHDPI resolution phones but this happened only in this devices.

Any pointers will be highly helpful.

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/allImageView"
android:src="@drawable/AllImage"/>
<ImageView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/backImageView"
android:src="@drawable/BackImage"/>
<ImageView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/leftImageView"
android:src="@drawable/LeftImage"/>
<ImageView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/right`enter code here`ImageView"
android:src="@drawable/RightImage"/>
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:src="@drawable/unknown"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 android:id="@+id/UnknownImageView" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

> Crash LOG
>
> Package: com.abc.xyz
>   Version Code: 21
>   Version Name: 21
>   Android: 7.0
>   Android Build: NPN25.137-15-2
>   Manufacturer: motorola
>   Model: XT1635-02
>   Thread: main-1
>   CrashReporter Key: 705C5100-EC27-C99F-E823-965A4C51E329DF46F9DD
>   Start Date: Mon Jul 03 16:53:04 GMT+05:30 2017
>   Date: Mon Jul 03 17:17:03 GMT+05:30 2017
>   Format: Xamarin
>
> Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: 
>   System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0xbefd1808 
>   (key_handle 0xee52e28) of Java type 
>   'md5fae2d7276310b1283693420df3d731df/SampleView' as managed type 
>   'MobileApp.Droid.Views.SampleView'. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary 
>   XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class  ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class 
>    ---> Java.Lang.ReflectiveOperationException: Exception of type
>   'Java.Lang.ReflectiveOperationException' was thrown. ---> 
>   Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 15810572 byte allocation with > 1711936 free bytes and 1671KB until OOM
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] > in :0 
>    at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod 
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, 
>   Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00082] in 
>   :0 
>    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod 
>   (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) 
>   [0x00019] in :0 
>    at Android.Views.View.Inflate (Android.Content.Context context, System.Int32 > resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root) [0x00073] in 
>   <7f31f6af154d41c2bc02beb149fde7ee>:0 
>    at MobileApp.Droid.Views.SampleView.Initialize () [0x00006] in 
>   :0 
>    at MobileApp.Droid.Views.SampleView..ctor (Android.Content.Context context, 
>   Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs) [0x00008] in 
>   :0 
>    at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:1c1e10c7-efc5-4985-b342-
>   f7e8755679f4 (intptr,object[])
>    at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr 
>   jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr signature_ptr, System.IntPtr > jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x000fb] in 
>   <7f31f6af154d41c2bc02beb149fde7ee>:0 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr 
>   jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr signature_ptr, System.IntPtr > jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x00189] in 
>   <7f31f6af154d41c2bc02beb149fde7ee>:0 
>    at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:a36f9a92-3454-42f0-9910-
>   ef12350699c2 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>     at mono.android.TypeManager.n_activate(Native Method)
>     at mono.android.TypeManager.Activate(TypeManager.java:7)
>     at md5fae2d7276310b1283693420df3d731df.SampleView.(SampleView.java:30)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>     at 
>   uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.
>   createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211)
>     at > uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000
>   (CalligraphyLay>outInflater.java:20)
>     at > uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater
>   $PrivateWrapperFactory2.on>CreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
>     at
>
> android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>     at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.
>   inflate(CalligraphyLayout>Inflater.java:60)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>     at md5a36dbcf21d3fe8ab142ce63b52c6ee92.CarHealthTyreFragment.
>   n_onCreateView(Native >Method)
>     at md5a36dbcf21d3fe8ab142ce63b52c6ee92.CarHealthTyreFragment.
>   onCreateView(CarHealt>hTyreFragment.java:39)
>     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.
>   moveToState(FragmentManager.java:129>9)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.
>   moveFragmentToExpectedState(Fragment>Manager.java:1528)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.
>   moveToState(FragmentManager.java:159>5)
>     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord. 
>   executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.
>   executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355>)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.
>   executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
>     at 
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.
>   optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.
>   execSingleAction(FragmentManager.jav>a:1979)

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That would include the Java stack trace of the OOM and the source code of yours that is referenced in that stack trace. "if there is a problem with the image then it should be appearing in every XXHDPI resolution phones" -- not necessarily. Not every device has the same heap limit, and the state of heap fragmentation is not necessarily deterministic.

Comment: updated the question with crash logs

Comment: You are attempting to allocate 15,810,572 bytes. That is equivalent to a 1988 x 1988 pixel image, and that is far too large.